# Google Analytics: How to add 'seconds' to dimension?

Tags: time, google-analytics, service-provider

In Google Analytics I have dimensions available for hours and minutes. Is there an easy way to also have seconds?

I know that I could do custom dimensions, but I don't want to change my tracking code if possible.

Why I want this:
I search for the service provider (B2B customer) and want to track the steps (pages) a service provider did. I need this in chronological order and without seconds this is very inaccurate.

Answer (score 1):

Inside Google Analytics this is not enable, but you can use code to extract this information from the computer (it's not the most accurate way because the second will based on the computer where the code is placed), but it can be an option for you

First you have to create a function to extract the second

```js
function gaTime(){ 
var date = new Date;
return date.getSeconds();
}
```

and then use that on every desired hit, in this case, i used the code on the pageiew (you can replace this line for the one inside the main snippet placing the function before)

```js
ga('send', 'pageview', {
  'dimensionxx':  gaTime()
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be the only option for now and I will try to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics does not offer agitation deeper then minute.  You could technically do it yourself using a Custom Dimension. However this will not change the resulting data calculations.

there is currently an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=389&q=unix&colspec=Component%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary) request for Ga:unixtime that might help with this but they have already stated that it wont aggregate down below minute.

> Even if we are able to create this dimension the Analytics Reporting
>   API only reports data in aggregate and as such the finest grain
>   reporting would be minute